# Nested request with retrofit2 + rxjava and ignore error in child request

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I use retrofit2 and I'm learning RxJava (with Retrolambda). I'm trying to achieve following flow:

1. get list of user
2. for each user, get user detail info for given user_id.
3. return list of user with detail.

This is my code so far:

```
getUsers().flatMapIterable(users -> users)
flatMap(user -> getDetailInfo(user.getID()
        .doOnNext(detailInfo -> user.setDetailInfo(detailInfo))
        .map(detailInfo -> user))
.toList().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
subscribe(users -> {}, error -> {});
```

The problem is when getDetailInfo gave 404 response, the observable enter to error scope even getUsers gave 200 response. How do I get the response enter to user scope as long as getUsers gave 200 response?

Hope I been enough clear.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with `.onErrorReturn()` ?

Comment: I tried to add `.onErrorReturn(throwable -> user)` after `.map`. It works, but I wanna make sure is it the right implementation? thanks

Comment: I think it's the right way, `onErrorReturn` instructs an Observable to emit a particular item when it encounters an error, and then terminate normally.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid your 404 to destroy your stream you should use `onErrorResumeNext` to convert your error into a default response like `null` and then you stream will survive even when the chained requests return error.

Comment: Where should i put `onErrorResumeNext`? I tried to put it on Observable `getDetailInfo()` with `Observable.empty()` as return. Instead of get list of user, I get an empty list. thanks

Comment: 'Observable.empty()' emits a 'onCompleted' signal, try to emit null instead

Comment: When I add `.OnErrorResumeNext(throwable -> null)`, the subscribe enters error scope. If I add `.OnErrorResumeNext(throwable -> Observable.just(null))`, the subscribe enters success scope but return empty list of user.

Comment: OnErrorResumeNext substitutes a new stream when an error is detected in the Observable...not quite what the posted intended.  I think he wants the previous observable stream to continue if there's an error and I don't know of a way to do that either.  I'm hitting a similar issue w/ a REST API :-(